# Rails assets precompile failing undefined variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I was recently assigned a task to change the theme of the site. Originally it was using bootstrap, and I used a bootswatch theme to re-theme it. Everything works fine and looks good locally. But I have to precompile my assets before I can deploy it to production.

```
`$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
```

is failing with the following error. I spent days digging through on the internet but no help to Avail.

Using jruby-1.7.18

**Portion of Gemfile**

```
# Styling
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails'
gem 'jquery_datepicker'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'therubyrhino'
gem 'less-rails'
```

**ERROR**

```
`** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Less::ParseError: variable @alert-padding is undefined
  (in /Users/hnaras2967c/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/twitter-bootswatch-rails-3.3.2.0/vendor/toolkit/twitter/bootstrap/alerts.less)
at /Users/hnaras2967c/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:604 (anonymous)
at org/mozilla/javascript/gen//Users/hnaras2967c/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:604 (anonymous)
/Users/hnaras2967c/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/therubyrhino-2.0.4/lib/rhino/context.rb:259:in `open'
/Users/hnaras2967c/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/therubyrhino-2.0.4/lib/rhino/context.rb:252:in `open'
/Users/hnaras2967c/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@cimport/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/java_script/rhino_context.rb:37:in `exec'`
```

Comment: If you go into a little more detail on what you've spent days trying, that might help you get an answer quicker.

Answer (score 0):

There should probably be an bootsrap-overrides or similar less stylesheet where you should be defining the @alert-padding variable